# public solvers for the time-dependent Schrödinger equation?

Tags: hyperbolic-pde

Are there efficient public solvers for the time-dependent Schrödinger equation with time-independent Hamiltonian and 2 or 3 degrees of freedom?

Answer (score 3):

I found the following package

https://www.pci.uni-heidelberg.de//tc/usr/mctdh/doc/

featuring the multiconfiguration time-dependent Hartree (MCTDH) method for distinguishable particles. The method is recommended for up to 12 degrees of freedom, though bigger systems have been treated , too.